# Need to get the VirtualMachine metadata of Azure cloud in JSON format, from JAVA

Tags: java, json, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I need to fetch the metadata of Azure VM in the same output as CLI command `az vm show -g resource-group -n name` gives.

When I am trying to fetch the details from JAVA, the method will return an object of Interface **VirtualMachine** and, I am also unable to parse that object into **JSON**.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachine;
    for (VirtualMachine vm : azure.virtualMachines().list()) {
Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().create();
            String jsonFromInstance = gsonBuilder.toJson(vm.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonFromInstance);

}
```

here I need to get the details from VM in JSON format as Azure CLI gives
If I create that JSON from me it will not be easy to do it for all other different resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/java#get-information-about-the-vm

I cannot follow this approch for every resourece, is there any method which gives me the same response in azure or any way to convert that object details into json.

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can try to convert the object to json

Comment: I need to parse the attributes of the vm object, like vm.disks() vm.name(). All these informations i need in one single json same as the DescribeInstance in AWS, and az vm show CLI command in Azure gives.

Comment: @JimXu I've tried converting the object, but didn't worked.

Comment: Could you please tell me the error and provide me the code?

Comment: @JimXu The code is same as it is in the link I provided above, and the error while I am parsing the vm object is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: According to my understanding, the ``` VirtualMachines``` is an interfac. So we cannot directly convert it to json. According to the situation, I suggest you use Azure rest api to get the information of VM : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get

Comment: @JimXun How can I do it with a java code, because I have to write a script for some of the resources in azure account and gather the metadata properties of them, like Vms StorageAccounts, Batches,Ad etc. So is there any management dependency for this where I can find the required classes for this work.

Comment: As far as I knew, we have no way to implement your need with java sdk. if you want to implement it, you just can refer to  [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/java#get-information-about-the-vm) or call Azure rest api